# CDROM drive suddenly not recognised

Tags: mount, fstab, cd-drive

[xubuntu 16.10]
I was ripping a cd in banshee and it froze half way through. I restarted banshee and it didn't recognise the cd, thunar no longer showing the drive.
I read a number of questions on here but they don't seem to have done anything:

`sudo lshw` shows:

```
 *-scsi:3
      physical id: 5
      logical name: scsi7
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: SCSI CD-ROM
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@7:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         capabilities: audio
         configuration: status=open
```

Status doesn't change whether there's a cd in the drive or not or the platter is open.

I created a folder: `/media/cdrom` [and tried](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353803/ubuntu-wont-recognize-dvd-drive):

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
```

but get: `mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0`

[I added this to fstab](https://superuser.com/questions/264465/my-dvd-rom-is-not-showing-up-in-media-or-in-mount-for-ubuntu-10-10):

```
/dev/sr0   /media/cdrom   udf,iso9660   user,noauto,exec,utf8   0   0
```

And rebooted but nothing changed. Super weird. Any thoughts? I haven't tried [changing my SATA cables](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1367690) yet, I don't think I have any spare ports. Thanks in advance!

Edit: the drive seems to be intermittently recognised by BIOS during boot. It was recognised in this boot cycle but `lshw` no longer lists it. Sounds hardware buggy right?

Edit2: changed to a free SATA, was on a raid now isn't. lshw says:

```
 *-scsi:2
      physical id: 3
      logical name: scsi2
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: BD-RE  GGW-H20L
         vendor: HL-DT-ST
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: YL05
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Now in /dev/ I have cdrom, cdrw, dvd, dvdrw, all link to sr0
I retried the fstab line & `mount` but no improvement, not listed.
In thunar as roof I see cdrom but clicking it gives:

```
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

But putting a CD in might have made it work. Testing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that this really is a thing after upgrading: went from 16.04 to 16.10 and had to switch SATA ports AND edit fstab. Irritante.