# Opening an .sh file from DVD Drive

Tags: scripts, xfce, dvd

I'm running **XFCE 4.12** and I got a CD with an **.sh** file I have to **run**. I don't know how.

Can I do this over the graphical interface or do I have to open the file in the terminal?

The **dvd-drive** is **not shown** in the "thunar file manager".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `terminal` and execute the script.

Open the terminal by <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+t</kbd>, then 
you can change directory (using `cd` to go to the directory where your script is, for example,

`cd /path to /DVD drive`

then

`./script.sh` to execute the script.

Or you can just execute by

`./full path/to/DVD drive/script.sh` to run the script.

---

One simple way to open the folder (in which your script is) is to right-click that folder and select `Open in terminal`. Then the `terminal` will open up and you can just run script as `./script.sh`

---

If you just cannot access your DVD disk using terminal or file-manager then you need to create a **mount point** (a folder in your file-system) where the contents of the disk is shown.

To do that:
You first decide where you want to mount the DVD drive.
`/mnt` or `/media` are appropriate.
Then create a folder under the `/mnt` or `/media` like following.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/dvdrw
```

Next, you need to find out the location of the dvd-drive under `/dev` ,

sudo lsblk -f

It may give output as `/dev/CD-ROM drive` or `/dev/DVD-RW drive` or `/dev/dvdrw` etc...

Finally, mount the DVD rom drive on the file-system by by entering the location under `/dev` and the path of the newly created folder ( for example, under `/mnt`) :

```
    sudo mount </dev/path to cd dvd disk>  <path to the folder for mounting>
```

for example,

```
sudo mount /dev/dvdrw /mnt/dvdrw
```

Comment: I dont know where the DVD-Drive is. how do i find out?

Comment: i cannot use your instruction because it does not show the dvd drive in the explorer.

Comment: By default it is under `/media/CD-ROM drive` or `/media/DVD drive`. So check under your `/media` folder

Comment: I searched for the /media folder but i couldnt find one. (both in terminal and graphical interface.

Comment: Open terminal by ctrl+alt+t, then execute this `mount|grep ^'/dev' `, then add the output received in your above question.Then it will be clear whether the DVD is read or not , and where is it mounted on the file system.

Comment: `./dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)` thats the output to mount|grep ^'

Comment: Then the DVD disk is not read. Probably the cable connecting the DVD drive to the motherboard is not secure. If the disk is read, it would appear in the output.

Comment: thats weird. but if i type `eject` in the terminal it **does** eject the dvd.

Comment: Oh. Then I guess DVD is  just not read. The eject would still work.

Comment: Check this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/353803/ubuntu-wont-recognize-dvd-drive

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved. Answer found. Had to create a mount point.

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you would take the time to describe how you created the mount point so that users without your expertise could learn from your experience. Or better yet, you could accept the answer from @ankit7540 whom actually helped you find your solution.

Comment: -1 not only did you not write an adequate answer, you didn't accept an answer which was a valid solution to the problem you described.