# PC running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop not mounting a SATA DVD/RW drive connected via USB

Tags: usb, 22.04, usb-drive, sata

I have a new mini PC running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop and wish to connect a SATA DVD/RW drive as an external device from my former PC where it was installed in one of the 5 1/2 in bays. I am using a SATA to USB powered adapter. My PC does not see the drive. What do I need to do so my PC recognizes and mounts the DVD/RW drive when connected using USB?
I tried following the suggestion from [ubuntu-wont-recognize-dvd-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353803/ubuntu-wont-recognize-dvd-drive). Using the CLI command: `sudo lshw -C disk` the system lists the NVMe drive and the internal SSD drive only.

```
  sudo lshw -C disk Output:

  *-namespace:0             
       description: NVMe disk
       physical id: 0
       logical name: hwmon0
  *-namespace:1
       description: NVMe disk
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/ng0n1
  *-namespace:2
       description: NVMe disk
       physical id: 1
       bus info: nvme@0:1
       logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
       size: 465GiB (500GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: guid=c84532ac-6562-4404-af07-571de437b7e7 
                      logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 
                      wwid=eui.002538d821a33175
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: Samsung SSD 860
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 4B6Q
       serial: S598NJ0N356841B
       size: 465GiB (500GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 
                      guid=4b74e481-1e7c-4246-84b4-e2f77a2095c7 
                      logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

Comment: Am I not supposed to see it listed as a device in Files under Other Locations and be able to read the contents of the CD?

Comment: I am just checking in terminal and in Files from the GNOME 42.5 menu

Comment: Just FYI:   I tried on a number of systems (*alas none jammy, but included Fedora & Debian as well as Ubuntu*) & if the drive is internal the `lshw` will show the results for optical drives, but I got no results if the drive was external.  I only have a single external optical drive so can't rule out hardware issues  (*drive was reacting to insertion of media etc.. but it'll do that when given power without connection to PC too so that means nothing*)

Comment: @guiverc Doesn't the OS need cdrom drivers installed in order to recognize and mount the drive?

Comment: For the internal drives I inserted no modules (`insmod`) to have them read.. As for external drives the *firmware* of the box can also be involved, but I'd have to know my drive is actually functional  (*I've not used mine in >2 years! so I can't assume it is*) but my *play* was with kernels as old as 5.10 & up to 6.1 which is older than *jammy* GA (5.15) or HWE (5.19) (*you said Desktop thus you'll be using 5.19 I bet*)

Comment: @guiverc I wonder if it is a power supply issue, I have a connector that supplies power with an AC adapter and has the data cable going to USB 2.0. That style cable works for my 3.5 HDDs connected to USB 2.0.

Comment: The *firmware* of the box can influence how the linux kernel sees hardware, some boxes will use external devices as if they're internal (*making it easier to use external media*) but others do not (*this is favored on hardware today as it makes it harder to boot external media which I believe is seen as a benefit to security*). If it's power issue you're off-topic here as this is a Ubuntu Q&A site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem of not being able to use an external DVD/RW drive with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as an external drive was to use a better quality `USB 3.0 to SATA III 6 Gbps Optical Storage Adapter`.

It was possible to connect the DVD/RW drive to a Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

As was suggested in the comments, there was no need to load any drivers, it just worked.